# nginx and nodejs serve images from dynamic folder

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-location

Hi i have this nginx setup:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name xxxxxx.xx www.xxxxxxx.xx;
root /home/xxxx/public_html;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    #proxy_redirect off; 
    #proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

My app creates folders inside the uploads/user followed by the user's ID and then stores images into it. Every user have his own folder inside uploads/user/xxxx.

ex.

```
/uploads/user/5878db663e67e3535a47c638/1085.github-logo.png
```

The app works fine in browser but when the user uploads the image it cannot be displayed so a 404 rises.

what can i do?

Comment: Do you want `nginx` to serve the uploaded files? Is `/uploads` directory under the `/home/xxxx/public_html` path?

Comment: the absolute path is `/home/xxxx/public_html/uploads/user/`.

Yes, i want nginx to serve the uploaded files.

Comment: I am doing the same thing for image storage by user folder. But my questions is how can use serve image in expressjs. because image folder create dynamically by userId.
app.use('/image', express.static('uploads/images/userId))
Then how to get userId if new user created after nodejs server started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try_files` to serve up static content (if it exists) and otherwise defer to NodeJS:

```
root /home/xxxx/public_html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: now the page won't load at all. I navigated to the image in browser and express responds with 404 in json format.

Comment: discard previous comment. I had a typo in /home/xxx part. The image loads fine, now the site throws 403 forbidden. I ll check out why and i'll come back.

Comment: Not sure if the `$uri/` term is useful in your case - you might try using `try_files $uri @proxy;` instead.