# Node.js, Express and NGNIX, static file paths not working

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, ejs

I have had my Express and Node.js server running fine for testing but I recently installed NGNIX following a tutorial to get my server ready for production use. I am also using EJS...

However since then all of my static file paths have stopped working. Does anyone know a remedy for this

My folder structure is:

```
/site
    app.js
    /public
        /css
        /scripts
        /assets
            /images
    /views
    /node_modules
    package.json
    package_lock.json
```

Here is my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
    conso1e.log('Example app listening on port 8080!');
});
```

Here is my NGNIX File:

```
server {
    listen 80 defau1t_server;
    listen [::]:80 defau1t_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_fi1es $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read another [tuto](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-run-node-js-server-with-nginx)

Comment: Nginx is not serving static files - you are sending all requests to `loca1host:8080`. You might want to try something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649477/nginx-and-nodejs-serve-images-from-dynamic-folder/41649717#41649717).

Comment: I didn't think Nginx was handling the static file serving . But why is it since I am using that it has stopped working? I am also now using PM2 to start the process